# Restricting a java method to be called by methods with specific annotation

Tags: java, annotations, testng

I am writing tests for some sftp validations and I run an embedded sftp server.

so I have a class like:

```
public class SftpServer {

    //method to initialize server
    public void init(){};

    //method to stop server
    public void stop(){};

   }
```

Now as my tests run in multithreaded environment I want the server to be started or stopped only once, I am using  `TestNG` as the Unit Testing Framework.

so I want the `init` and the `stop` methods to be only called with methods `annotated` with `@BeforeSuite` or `@AfterSuite` annotations, I know that java docs maybe a way to suggest getting it done this way but I wish to **Enforce** it, is it possible in java to impose this restriction in some way?

Comment: No, annotations just hold meta information for the compiler and cannot restrict access to methods.

Comment: what about finding the annotation class name of the calling method and throwing an exception if it's not the right annotation?

Comment: find the calling method and use reflection to resolve its annotations :)

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to get the calling method's annotation class name

Comment: There's no standard way of doing it, so it would involve a lot of hacky code for very little advantage.

Comment: What you are attempting is called 'state orientation' and it was discarded as conceptually flawed in the 1960s.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best option to do what you want, but you will be able to achieve it anyway:

```
public void test() {
    StackTraceElement element = getElement();
    try {
        Method m = Class.forName(element.getClassName()).getDeclaredMethod(element.getMethodName());
        Annotation[] annotations = m.getAnnotations();
        // do your thing
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static StackTraceElement getElement() {
    StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (int i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
        StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = elements[i];
        if (!stackTraceElement.getClassName().equals(Bar.class.getName())
                && !stackTraceElement.getMethodName().equals("getElement()")
                && stackTraceElement.getClassName().indexOf("java.lang.Thread") != 0) {
            return stackTraceElement;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

With the annotation list at hand for the caller method, just look for the one you want and do whatever you have to.

This consider that the caller method is from another class, so adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are two general ways to enforce this.

One is for the `init` and `stop` methods to perform run-time checking.  When called, they would examine the stack, determine their caller, reflectively determine the annotation on their caller, and throw an exception if the caller is not annotated wih `@BeforeSuite` or `@AfterSuite`.  This does not prevent you from writing incorrect calls, it just crashes your test suite if you wrote the incorrect calls.

The other approach is static checking.  When compiling a method that calls `init` or `stop`, the compiler would issue an error if the method is not annotated wih `@BeforeSuite` or `@AfterSuite`.  This gives you earlier notification of errors, at compile time, and thus prevents you from ever running incorrect code.  To implement this, you would write an annotation processor using a tool like the [Checker Framework](http://CheckerFramework.org/) or a plugin to a tool like [error-prone](https://github.com/google/error-prone).